# Scroll to href with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, easing

I have this code.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

How can I make this script with a super smooth easing effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the `href` attribute before calling `animate`, otherwise the scope of `this` is incorrect.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  height: 2000px;
}
#inner {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#inner">Go to #inner</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div id="inner">I'm the #inner element.</div>
```

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. Thanks, @Shiala. But I don't get the difference between `$("a").attr("href")` and `$("a")[0].href`. Both return type `string`; however, the latter cannot be used as a jQuery selector string.

Comment: Well I was wrong, cause I did not understand the concept of the question, about your question why the latter didn't work that's cause JavaScript actually returns the page link + the href value when you do element.href

Comment: thanks for the snippet and for explaining what the user failed to mention in the question

Comment: Oh, duh -- using `.href` includes the full URL even if the `href` attribute only specifies a fragment id.